# Heroku Load Time "Connection Reset and empty page sometime"

Tags: facebook, performance, caching, heroku

I have hosted a Facebook app on Heroku. The code was perfect on my server but when I hosted it on Heroku and the entries in the database become more it is now showing blank page sometime and it shows Connection reset problem.... What should I do ? I am in the middle of the contest. Though I have installed ClearDB MySQL Database Punch,MemCachier 100 MB and 5 dynos for the host. Please help me what should I do now ?

Comment: can you show what libraries are you using for connecting to the DB on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you close the **db connection** each time you open it. Also increase the **memory_limit** in the php.ini.